Introductory textbook on session types
What is a good/standard textbook on session types? I'm looking for more information on semantics for session-types-like languages, their features (branching, recursion, etc.), properties, and if interesting, proofs of those properties. I'm looking for one for both learning and citation purposes. Essentially, it'd be great if there is an analogue of "Introduction to Choreographies" 1 for session types, but besides Wen's extensive blog post 2, I haven't found it yet. If there's a standard set of papers you recommend that would also be appreciated.
